# wrong time using NSDateFormatter

Tags: swift, time, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know there is several question about this. But i tried all the recommendation and still the time doesn't match the time atonmy real device.

```
    let dater = NSDate()
    let dayTimePeriodFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dayTimePeriodFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dayTimePeriodFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "H:s" 
    var dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.stringFromDate(dater)
```

**Device(real) time : 22:11 . dateString output : 00:36**

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the timezone to UTC, which I'm guessing is not the timezone you're in. You probably want to set it to `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()`

Comment: Hey @NickWhite . Thanks. But when i change it to SystemTimeZone the result is 00:58, while the needed time is 00:43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nick points out, you're using UTC as your time zone, and you can get to the local time zone with `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()`

It's also likely that you don't really intend to use just the hours (H) and seconds (s)  You probably also want the minutes (m).  Try using a dateFormat of "H:m:s"

Better yet, use "H:mm:ss" which will force the minutes and seconds to be two digits, as opposed to just one, so you don't wind up with "10:4:3"

Comment: Hey! Thanks. But when i change it to SystemTimeZone the result is 00:58, while the needed time is 00:43

Comment: I'm making replica of the Lock Screen so i just need the h/m

Comment: Did you try changing the dateFormat as recommended also?

Comment: If you just need hours and minutes, use "H:m"  in either case you don't want "H:s"

Comment: Oh wow. I can actually throw the 2 years of experience to the trash, Can't believe i haven't notice this haha! Thank you! I used "s" instead of "m"! LOL

Comment: And better than either is really "H:mm" which will force the minutes to be 2 digits instead of 1 or 2, so you don't wind up with "10:4" but get "10:04" which is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you David. Sometimes overthinking is the wrong move haha. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"`?

Apple uses fixed Internet. Check out [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) to see some examples. This may be helpful